# How to fix 'IMvcBuilder' doesn't contain a definition for 'AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters'

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the latest .Net Core v2.1.4.

I tried to add `AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();` in the `Startup.cs` file but it reports that `IMvcBuilder` doesn't contain a definition for it.

My `startup.cs`:

```
{
    services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();

    app.Run(async(context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("MVC didn't find anything!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you missing `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` in your file?

Comment: I have already added them :(

"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;"

Comment: Do you have a reference to the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcxmlmvcbuilderextensions.addxmldatacontractserializerformatters?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_MvcXmlMvcBuilderExtensions_AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IMvcBuilder_) extension method is in the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml/). Make sure you have this included in your project. Either using the Nuget package manager UI or from the command line:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml
```

Additionally, ensure you are importing the the namespace with:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```