# AddRazorRuntimeCompilation causing deployment problems

Tags: web-deployment

When I try to deploy my project it fails with the following message:-

```
Startup.cs(75,25): error CS1061: 'IMvcBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddRazorRuntimeCompilation' 
and no accessible extension method 'AddRazorRuntimeCompilation' accepting a first argument of type 'IMvcBuilder' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I found an answer here [How to fix 'IMvcBuilder' doesn't contain a definition for 'AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546997/how-to-fix-imvcbuilder-doesnt-contain-a-definition-for-addxmldatacontractser) however after installing the suggested MVC formatter package(s) The issue persisted.

The only way I have been able to deploy is to comment out the following lines in my startup class

```
var builder = services.AddRazorPages();
if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Maybe I need to update something on the deployment server? It is the organisation's first DotNet Core 3.1 application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation, but not the latest version. Something compatible with .Net Core 3.x.

E.g.

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 3.1.19

Comment: Although my issue was already solved by the time of this answer, this was the solution which is why I marked it as the correct answer.
And yes, I should have updated the question with my solution earlier.